# Load PLY vertex color with Qt3D

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, vtk, qt3d

I am trying to load a PLY mesh file, with per vertex color data, using Qt3D. After some research it seems not so straightforward: [QML load and display .ply mesh with color attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786536/qml-load-and-display-ply-mesh-with-color-attributes)

Another option I tried was to use VTK but it lacks support for Qt Quick.

I am trying to create a PLY file previewer. Is there any simple way to do this using Qt Quick?

Comment: Have you tried using `QSceneLoader`?